# Using C# with OpenOffice through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on some code to paste into the currently active [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) document directly from C#.  I can't include any of the OpenOffice libraries, because we don't want to package them, so we're using reflection to get access to the [OpenOffice API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects).

My question involves using a dispatcher through reflection.  I can't figure out the correct parameters to pass to it, giving me a lovely "TargetInvocationException" due to mismatched types.

```
object objframe = GetProperty<object>(objcontroller, "frame");
if (objframe != null)
{
    object[] paramlist = new object[2] {".uno:Paste", objframe};
    InvokeMethod<object>(objdispatcher, "executeDispatch", paramlist);
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is it just me or are your parameters the wrong way around? Also, do you have the right number of parameters? I could be missing something though, so sorry if you've already checked this stuff:

The documentation says:

```
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Paste", "", 0, Array())
```

Which would indicate to me that you need to have your parameter list defined as

```
object[] paramlist = new object[5] {objframe, ".uno:Paste", "", 0, null};
```